# Unable to display Bing maps on Window Phone 7 emulator

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, windows-phone-7.1

I am using this basic code to display Bing Maps on my window phone 7 emulator.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <my:Map Height="462" CredentialsProvider="My Regestered Key" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" />
            <Button Content="Zoom In" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,535,0,0" Name="buttonZoomIn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Click="buttonZoomIn_Click" />
            <Button Content="Road Mode" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,474,0,0" Name="buttonRoad" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Click="buttonRoad_Click" />
            <Button Content="Zoom Out" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="243,535,0,0" Name="buttonZoomOut" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Click="buttonZoomOut_Click" />
            <Button Content="Aerial Mode" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="243,474,0,0" Name="buttonAerial" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Click="buttonAerial_Click" />
        </Grid>
```

But every time i get this error Message  "Unable to contact server Please try again Later"

I have registered key with Application Type(Developer)

Proxy settings are also done and emulator's browser is able to access websites.

I am using Microsoft visual studio 2010 and windows phone 7 emulator.

I am not getting what is going wrong.

Thanks and Regards.

Now i installed this on window phone device and the map is loaded  but not on emulator.

do someone has an answer.

Comment: Have you tried it without the CredentialsProvider?

Comment: I tried it without credential Provider than also it gives same thing.

Comment: Does this post help you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462089(VS.92).aspx

Comment: I have already gone through this post and as i mentioned i can browse websites through emulator. It just not wrking with maps.

Comment: You need internet access for it to work in the emulator. There's nothing more to it than that.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen  As i said i able to access websites on my emulators browser, which means internet access is available with the emulator.

Comment: Clearly your firewall, proxy or random other shizzle disables access to Bing Maps then. If it works on the device, it's not a software development problem, and as such don't belong here.

Comment: Also try closing the emulator / restarting your computer. I've had this issue and it was resolved by a fresh emulator.